# WSO2 secondary user store login without domain prefix?

Tags: wso2

If the usernames across the primary and secondary user stores are globally unique, is it possible to configure WSO2 (API Manager) to accept usernames from the secondary store *without* requiring the user store domain prefix, e.g. `userstore/username`?

Comment: You should be able to log in without given the userstore.

Comment: @Pubci Oh my gosh.  You are right!  I'm slapping my head right now.  If you want to answer the question, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to provide the userstore when login to store, publisher and admin.